# Display none and display block, animation css

Tags: javascript, php, css

I used js for function onclick:

```
    var x = document.getElementById("galeriabramy");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

My code php and html

```
           <h4 onclick="wzorBramyClick()" style="cursor: pointer;">
               <span>Wzory bram</span>
               <span class="span-fr"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/chervon-up.svg" /></span>
            </h4>
           <div id="galeriabramy" style="display: block;" class="col-12 gallery-block grid-gallery">
               <div class="row">
                   <?php
                   foreach( $media_wzory as $wzory ){
                       echo '<div class="col-md-3 item item-custom-gallery mb-3">';
                       echo '<a class="lightbox" href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($wzory['zdjecie_wzoru']).'">';
                       echo '<img class="img-gallery image scale-on-hover" src="'.wp_get_attachment_url($wzory['zdjecie_wzoru']).'">';
                       echo '<div class="w-100 text-center">';
                       echo '<h5>'.$wzory['nazwa_wzoru'].'</h5>';
                       echo '</div>';
                       echo '</a>';
                       echo '</div>';
                   }
                   ?>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

I would like to perform animation transition whith display none on display block

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transitions on the CSS display property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property)

Answer (score 0):

You can not animate the `display` property. If you want to fade in an element you can animate `opacity` instead or `transform` to move something in.

The `display` property does not only affect visuals but also layout of the site.